# Implication of "Somewhere"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, contemporary-english

I have a quick question.
If I'm writing: "Do you want to go somewhere with me?", does it sound like who is speaking has a specific place in mind or that they just want to go somewhere random?
I'm not a native speaker so sometimes it's hard for me to tell the difference with this type of nuances. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's difficult to provide a definitive answer. I would probably understand that the speaker was suggesting an outing for its own sake, but it's possible that they have somewhere in mind and are being deliberately mysterious.

Comment: Yes, both are equally likely, context is everything.

Comment: @NigelJ has it right. When so much information is lacking (who is "you"? who is "me"? what are their relationships/histories/genders/...?) the only thing one can do is guess, and for that the more context, the better.

Comment: Broadly, a native listener would hear "Do you want to… with me"… no "somewhere" nor even any "go". Does that make sense?